# dynamic join in linq 0 c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
   var query = from C in db.clients
    join O in db.orders on c.clientid equals O.clientid
    join P in db.products on O.productid equals P.productid
    select new {C,O};
```

I want to perform a search based on the above join. The input param could be

C.ClientID and/or P.ProductName and/or P.ProductType and/or  O.ShippingType

How would i build a dynamic search clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method:

```
Expression<Func<Client, bool>> clientWhere = c => true;
Expression<Func<Order, bool>> orderWhere = o => true;
Expression<Func<Product, bool>> productWhere = p => true;

if (filterByClient)
{
    clientWhere = c => c.ClientID == searchForClientID;
}

if (filterByProductName)
{
    productName = p => p.ProductName == searchForProductNameString;
}

// other filter cases

var query = from C in db.clients.Where(clientWhere)
    join O in db.orders.Where(orderWhere) on c.clientid equals O.clientid
    join P in db.products.Where(productWhere) on O.productid equals P.productid
    select new {C,O};
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's [Dynamic LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx). Here's [a nice intro from Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). With Dynamic LINQ, you can build your conditionals.  For example,

```
Where("ClientId = 12")
```