# Exception using OrElse and AndAlso expression methods

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions, dynamic-linq

I am trying to build an expression tree programmatically.

I have in my input, a list of condition classes which have the following form:

```
public class Filter
{
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string operator { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

When I build the `Expression` object I create an `Expression` for every condition in the following way

```
foreach ( Filter sf in rules ) {
    Expression ex = sf.ToExpression( query );
    if ( mainExpression == null ) {
        mainExpression = ex;
    }
    else {
        if ( logicalCondition == "AND" ) {
            mainExpression = Expression.And( mainExpression, ex );
        }
        else if ( logicalCondition == "OR" ) {
            mainExpression = Expression.Or( mainExpression, ex );
        }
    }
}
```

The Filter.ToExpression() method is implemented like this

```
public override Expression ToExpression( IQueryable query ) {
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter( query.ElementType, "p" );
    MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
    foreach ( var property in field.Split( '.' ) )
        memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property( memberAccess ?? ( parameter as Expression ), property );
    ConstantExpression filter = Expression.Constant( Convert.ChangeType( value, memberAccess.Type ) );
    WhereOperation condition = (WhereOperation)StringEnum.Parse( typeof( WhereOperation ), operator );
    LambdaExpression lambda = BuildLambdaExpression( memberAccess, filter, parameter, condition, value );
    return lambda;
}
```

Everything works when I have a single condition but when I try to combine expressions using one of the `And`, `Or`, `AndAlso`, `OrElse` static methods I receive an `InvalidOperationException` that says:

> The binary operator Or is not defined for the types
>   'System.Func`2[MyObject,System.Boolean]' and
>   'System.Func`2[MyObject,System.Boolean]'.

I am getting a little bit confused. Can somebody better explain the reasons of the exception and suggest a solution?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You're combining `a => a == 3` and `a => a == 4` into `(a => a == 3) || (a => a == 4)`, but you should instead be trying to make it `a => (a == 3 || a == 4)`. This is not too hard to do manually, but [someone has done it for you already](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx). Look for "Combining Expressions".

**Edit**: as requested, a simple example of how to do this manually.

**Edit 2**: it uses `ExpressionVisitor` which is new to .NET 4, but [at MSDN you can find a usable implementation for earlier versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx#Y0). I'm assuming MSDN code doesn't qualify as "third party" for your purposes. You only need to change the `protected virtual Expression Visit(Expression exp)` method to `public`. And as `Enumerable.Zip` is unavailable for you and it isn't necessary, it is gone now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace DemoApp
{
    <include ExpressionVisitor definition here for .NET 3.5>

    public class ExpressionParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ExpressionParameterReplacer(IList<ParameterExpression> fromParameters, IList<ParameterExpression> toParameters)
        {
            ParameterReplacements = new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
            for (int i = 0; i != fromParameters.Count && i != toParameters.Count; i++)
                ParameterReplacements.Add(fromParameters[i], toParameters[i]);
        }
        private IDictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> ParameterReplacements
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            ParameterExpression replacement;
            if (ParameterReplacements.TryGetValue(node, out replacement))
                node = replacement;
            return base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Expression<Func<int, bool>> exprA = a => a == 3;
            Expression<Func<int, bool>> exprB = b => b == 4;
            Expression<Func<int, bool>> exprC =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<int, bool>>(
                    Expression.OrElse(
                        exprA.Body,
                        new ExpressionParameterReplacer(exprB.Parameters, exprA.Parameters).Visit(exprB.Body)),
                    exprA.Parameters);
            Console.WriteLine(exprA.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(exprB.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(exprC.ToString());
            Func<int, bool> funcA = exprA.Compile();
            Func<int, bool> funcB = exprB.Compile();
            Func<int, bool> funcC = exprC.Compile();
            Debug.Assert(funcA(3) && !funcA(4) && !funcA(5));
            Debug.Assert(!funcB(3) && funcB(4) && !funcB(5));
            Debug.Assert(funcC(3) && funcC(4) && !funcC(5));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I can't use third party code to solve this problem. Can you please better explain which would be' the way for doing it manually? Thanks again!

Comment: @Lorenzo Sure, I've added a program based on the two expressions I used as an example.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to implement your solution. I did understand that the `ExpressionVisitor` comes from the LinqKit sources and I have been able to see how it works. The question now is: where the `Zip` method of `IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>` comes from? I am using .NET 3.5 and I am not able to find that method :(

Comment: @Lorenzo Ah, I was using .NET 4, which comes with both the `ExpressionVisitor` class and the `Enumerable.Zip` extension method. I'll see if I can get something working for 3.5 too, but that'll be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Lorenzo As it turns out, MS has posted a functional `ExpressionVisitor` on MSDN, so I tested to see whether it works (it does) and made a mention of it. And `Enumerable.Zip` isn't really necessary, so I dropped it and added a simple `for` loop in its place.

Comment: Exactly! And I was complaining why doesn't it just execute the lambdas that return bool and then ORs them :) All I needed was to restructure my code a bit so that I'm generating a boolean expression with all the ORs, and then put that into a lambda!