# System.Linq.Expressions: Binding LambdaExpression inputs at runtime

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following setup:

```
class A { public int x; }
class B { public int y; }

static class Helper
{
    public static Expression<Func<B>> BindInput(
        Expression<Func<A, B>> expression,
        A input)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<Func<B>> e = Helper.BindInput(
        (A a) => new B { y = a.x + 3 },
        new A { x = 4 });

    Func<B> f = e.Compile();
    Debug.Assert(f().y == 7);
}
```

What I want to do in the method `BindInput` is transform the expression to have `input` embedded into it. In the example usage in `Main`, the resulting expression `e` would be

```
() => new B { y = input.x + 3 }
```

where `input` is the second value that was passed into `BindInput`.

How would I go about doing this?

**Edit:**

I should add that the following expression `e` is **not** what I'm looking for:

```
((A a) => new B { y = a.x + 3 })(input)
```

This would be fairly trivial to obtain because it just involves adding a layer on top of the existing expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After lots of searching I stumbled across the magic `ExpressionVisitor` class. The following seems to be working perfectly:

```
class MyExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression TargetParameterExpression { get; private set; }
    public object TargetParameterValue { get; private set; }
    public MyExpressionVisitor(ParameterExpression targetParameterExpression, object targetParameterValue)
    {
        this.TargetParameterExpression = targetParameterExpression;
        this.TargetParameterValue = targetParameterValue;
    }
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node == TargetParameterExpression)
            return Expression.Constant(TargetParameterValue);
        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}

static class Helper
{
    public static Expression<Func<B>> BindInput(Expression<Func<A, B>> expression, A input)
    {
        var parameter = expression.Parameters.Single();
        var visitor = new MyExpressionVisitor(parameter, input);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<B>>(visitor.Visit(expression.Body));
    }
}
```