# Multiple Left Joins and dynamic where

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm pretend to build a search page for a products
Whit multiples form variables and integrates them to this query..
dynamically.. in where clauses of independents class like ProductoAtributo or others

And the d

**T-SQL QUERY  ( That I want )**

```
SELECT 
    p.*, tpa.*, pa.*, tp.*
FROM 
    Producto p 
LEFT JOIN 
        ProductoAtributo pa ON pa.ProductoId=p.ProductoId
LEFT JOIN
        TipoProductoAtributo tpa ON tpa.AtributoId=pa.AtributoId AND tpa.TipoProductoId=p.TipoProductoId
LEFT JOIN
        TipoProducto tp ON p.TipoProductoId = tp.TipoProductoId
WHERE
        (pa.Valor = '3' AND pa.AtributoId=7) OR ( pa.Valor = '3' AND pa.AtributoId=6 )
```

**Dynamic Where -- UPDATED**

```
 Func<ProductoAtributo, bool> productoAtributoWhere = Pa => true;


            string CantidadDormitorios = "3";


            if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(CantidadDormitorios))
            {
                productoAtributoWhere = Pa => (Pa.Valor == CantidadDormitorios && Pa.AtributoId == 7) || (Pa.Valor == CantidadDormitorios && Pa.AtributoId == 6);
            }
```

**the attempting -> my closest aproach -- UPDATED**

```
var producto = from P in db.Producto
                           join Tp in db.TipoProducto on P.TipoProductoId equals Tp.TipoProductoId into tpjoin
                           from TpJ in tpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           join Pa in db.ProductoAtributo on P.ProductoId equals Pa.ProductoId into pajoin
                           from PaJ in pajoin.AsQueryable<ProductoAtributo>().Where(productoAtributoWhere).DefaultIfEmpty()
                           join Tpa in db.TipoProductoAtributo on PaJ.AtributoId equals Tpa.AtributoId into tpajoin
                           from TpaJ in tpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new { P };
            var producto1 = producto.ToList();
```

**THE ERROR**

```
Error   3   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SGI.Models.ProductoAtributo>' no contiene una definición para 'Where' y la mejor sobrecarga del método de extensión 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,bool>)' tiene algunos argumentos no válidos D:\Documentos\SGI6\SGI\Areas\Cotizacion\Controllers\CotizacionController.cs 55  22  Cotizacion

Error   4   Argumento 2: no se puede convertir de 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<SGI.Models.ProductoAtributo,bool>>' a 'System.Func<SGI.Models.ProductoAtributo,int,bool>'.    D:\Documentos\SGI6\SGI\Areas\Cotizacion\Controllers\CotizacionController.cs 55  35  Cotizacion
```

Before the left joins -> "from TpJ in tpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()"
no errors...
If i traslade the where to the " join Pa in db.ProductoAtributo" -> join Pa in db.ProductoAtributo.Where(productoAtributoWhere)
No errors too  ..however the t-sql query returns 3 register vs 26 the linq

without where ...linq and t-sql display the same results

Hope, you can help me ..
Greetings

**This the original query without the left joins  UPDATED**

```
var producto = from P in db.Producto
                           join Tp in db.TipoProducto on P.TipoProductoId equals Tp.TipoProductoId
                           join Pa in db.ProductoAtributo.Where(productoAtributoWhere) on P.ProductoId equals Pa.ProductoId
                           join Tpa in db.TipoProductoAtributo on Pa.AtributoId equals Tpa.AtributoId
                           select new { P };
            var producto1 = producto.ToList();
```

Comment: Could you please try running this with your .net localizations turned off, I cannot read the Exceptions in your code. Also I am having trouble working out what you mean by "dynamic" where. What is the logic for your `Where` Predicate?

Comment: i think `pajoin` already not is `ProductoAtributo` collection, so you need change your Expression Type

Comment: My logic of Where was exposed here .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1263587/493166

Comment: @DiegoOrtega do you have typing error in the query `from TpaJ in tpjoin.DefaultIfEmpty()` possibly you mean from `TpaJ in tpajoin.DefaultIfEmpty()`?

Comment: you are rigth, however now i got 28 rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your errors say that you try call method with wrong parameters, its because you predicate is Expression that using for `IQueryable` extensions, but when you use [join..into clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb311040.aspx) you get not `IQueryable`, but `IEnumeration`, so for solve i see two paths

**First:** change type of predicate from `Expression<Func<ProductoAtributo, bool>>` to `Func<ProductoAtributo, bool>`

OR

**Second:** convert your groupped result to `IQueryable` i.e.

```
....
join Pa in db.ProductoAtributo on P.ProductoId equals Pa.ProductoId into pajoin
from PaJ in pajoin.AsQueryable().Where(productoAtributoWhere).DefaultIfEmpty()
....
```

Comment: Grundy, thanks for your answer the errors dissapears.. however attemting 
      var producto1 = producto.ToList();

I Got a invalid Exeption
 1025 internal error .NET Framework Data Provider.

Comment: @DiegoOrtega, sorry, i do not quite understand what you mean, can you little more explain?

Comment: i attemting to convert linq result with toList() method an throws a invalid Exception in the process...

Comment: @DiegoOrtega, oh, i see that you apply all paths :-) try return back `Expression` for `productoAtributoWhere` declaration

Comment: the Exeption dissapears..however the results are diferents between T-sql ( 3 rows ) vs Linq ( 26 rows )

Comment: @DiegoOrtega it seems like `where expression` does not work, are you sure that you try it not with expressions `Pa=>true` ?

Comment: the where expression without the left join works like a charm !

Comment: @DiegoOrtega i have an idea! try swap `Where(productoAtributoWhere)` and `DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: @DiegoOrtega why you mark its an answer? you solve your problem with different count of returns row for sql and linq?

Comment: Yeah i solved that.. in my own answer ..i told was a problem of query in linq, combined with ... the location of the where..
without your help.. probably i wil don't finish ...read my answer..

Answer (score 1):

I installed Linqer... to translate t-sql to linq attached bin folder project, and connection to sql server...generate edml atuotmatically.. after that i got the correct linq to my query...

So far the error was put the `productoAtributoWhere` before the DefaultifEmpty(), when correct filter was after that...

Thanks @Grundy ..your's tips to the `Expressions`  and `AsQueryable` was powerfully.

**UPDATED CODE**

```
    Expression<Func<ProductoAtributo, bool>> productoAtributoWhere = pa => true;


                string CantidadDormitorios = "";


                if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(CantidadDormitorios))
                {
                    productoAtributoWhere = pa => (pa.Valor == CantidadDormitorios && pa.AtributoId == 7) || (pa.Valor == CantidadDormitorios && pa.AtributoId == 6);
                }

    var producto = from p in db.Producto
                                   join pa in db.ProductoAtributo on p.ProductoId equals pa.ProductoId into pa_join
                                   from pa in pa_join.DefaultIfEmpty().AsQueryable().Where( productoAtributoWhere )
                                   join tpa in db.TipoProductoAtributo
                                         on new { pa.AtributoId, p.TipoProductoId }
                                     equals new { tpa.AtributoId, tpa.TipoProductoId } into tpa_join
                                   from tpa in tpa_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   join tp in db.TipoProducto on p.TipoProductoId equals tp.TipoProductoId into tp_join
                                   from tp in tp_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
                           { p };
        var producto1 = producto.ToList();
```